# How to deal with null values in a Store when using the sum function

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I have the requirement that I need to group the value and sum of a stored field value. When summing the value I am getting NaN. I am getting null value from json response. Can anybody tell me how to replace null with 0 in store in extjs? Is there any other way to do avoid Nan while summing the fieldvalue?

```
clientDistributionStore.group(groupField);
curJANObj= clientDistributionStore.sum('curJAN',true);
```

I am getting null for some of 'curJAN' values so I am getting Nan error

Answer (score 0):

I got it through record.set functionality to set value 0 for null

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to add a new "converted" (I'd prefer to call it "computed") field to your model:

```
fields: [
  { name: 'curJan', type: 'int' },
  {  
     name: 'curJanNotNull', type: 'int',
     convert: function(val, row) {
       return row.curJan !== null ? row.curJan : 0;
     }  
  }
]

...

var janSum = clientDistributionStore.sum('curJanNotNull', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I resolved it this way.

```
clientDistributionStore.group(Ext.create('Ext.util.Grouper', {
    property: groupField,
    getGroupString: function (instance) {
        return instance.get(this.property) || 0;
    }
}));

curJANObj= clientDistributionStore.sum('curJAN',true); // return ex. {0: 100, 'John Smith': 1000}
```

`getGroupString` function can be implemented other way because now it treats empty string also as 0. You can modify it to your own needs but you can't return null value.

It works for ExtJS 4.2.1